# Update fields in Access 2010 Database Table

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I have a database with four tables in it. I am trying to update the Techs table. To do this I need to read the existing values, store them into memory, and add a values to the data. My problem occurs when i try to update the values back to the database I get a error saying there is a syntax error in my update statement.

```
string userName = "Admin";
int closed = 0;
decimal money = 0.00M;

string sql = "Select * From Techs WHERE TechName = @uName";
cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@uName", OleDbType.VarChar, 50); cmd.Parameters["@uName"].Value = userName;

cmd.Connection = conn;
dbReader = MakeReader(sql);
while (dbReader.Read())
{
        money = decimal.Parse(dbReader["Money"].ToString());
        closed = int.Parse(dbReader["#Closed"].ToString());
}
dbReader.Close();

//Proof of sucessful read
MessageBox.Show(money + ":" + closed);

string update = "Update Techs SET Money=@money, #Closed=@closed WHERE TechName=@uName";
OleDbCommand updateCmd = new OleDbCommand(update, conn);
updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@money", money + 12.00M);
updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@closed", closed + 1);
updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uName", userName);
updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Error here
```

Error message

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Money is a keyword, and #Closed contains a special character, both should be bracketed:

```
string update = "Update Techs SET [Money]=@money, [#Closed]=@closed WHERE TechName=@uName";
```

Personally, I'd avoid Money as a parameter name too, but unsure if that would cause trouble.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the problem and I was being an idiot.